# Fluke 393 checked resistance on a live circuit wonder if I damaged my meter

Tags: resistance, multimeter, protection, damage

I have a fluke-393 multimeter and I was testing voltage on a 480V circuit didn’t realize I was on resistance and when I put my probes on the circuit there was a small arc, quickly taking my probes off realizing I was on the wrong setting. I checked my Meter still says OL when my probes are not touching and I have little resistance with the probes touching. Was wondering if I possibly damaged my meter or if the meter has protection from this sort of thing.

Comment: that should be `zero resistance with the probes touching`

Comment: it shows 0.2 ohms - 0.0 ohms

Comment: probably ok ... that's why you pay the big bucks for a Fluke

Comment: OL with probes not touching is pretty normal, it'd get funky defining resistance of an air gap. Try measuring the resistance of an actual component to verify. Also, what are you doing measuring 480V (AC?) in the first place if you don't know what you're doing? That's no laughing matter voltage, unless it's some kind of restricted current bias voltage generator which stings but won't do more than that.

Comment: Sounds fine to me; the overload was probably absorbed by the protection circuitry. That's what it's there for, after all. Do open up the meter and check that there aren't any exploded varistors or anything, just to be safe, but you should be fine.